# How to run Git diff and show new location of moved file instead of old location?

Tags: git

I'm using the following command:
`git --no-pager diff --name-only 'origin/oldbranch'..'origin/newerbranch'`

This works perfectly I get a list of all the files that have been modified,deleted, or added since the oldbranch.

However, if a file is moved, but not modified, I get the location of where the file used to live and not the new location.

There doesn't seem to be an easy option to have git diff tell me the new location of the file. It seems I have to use `git log --name-only -- "**/themovedfile.txt"` to get back all results for where that file existed. While I could write some logic to deal with this it seems like overkill.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Use `--name-status` instead of `--name-only`: the `R` status includes both names.

Comment: That `--name-status` is helpful, however it still returns the old location of the file and not the new location.

Comment: Looks like if i turn off rename detection using `--no-renames` then get I get back the file as deleted and added with the old and new path.

Comment: @torek If I flip the branches to `'origin/newerbranch'..origin/oldbranch'` then your original suggestion works. I don't know if changing this is going to change my result set.

Comment: Hm, here's what I get for one example case: `R095    contrib/hooks/multimail/README  contrib/hooks/multimail/README.rst` (note presence of two names)

Comment: This technically answers my question. If you want to post the answer ill accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of noteworthy items here, but let's start with the answer:

```
git diff --name-only L R
```

compares the two specific commits, using your configured defaults (e.g., `diff.renames` and diff.renameLimit`), and gives you just the names of files that differ in commits *L* (for left) and *R* (for right).  If you reverse the two names, you get the same output.  If rename detection is in effect, you get the name that appears in commit *R:*

```
$ git diff 99177b34db^ 99177b34db --name-only
contrib/hooks/multimail/CHANGES
contrib/hooks/multimail/CONTRIBUTING.rst
contrib/hooks/multimail/README.Git
contrib/hooks/multimail/README.rst
contrib/hooks/multimail/doc/gitolite.rst
contrib/hooks/multimail/git_multimail.py
contrib/hooks/multimail/migrate-mailhook-config
contrib/hooks/multimail/post-receive.example
```

Switching to `--name-status` gets us more information:

```
$ git diff 99177b34db^ 99177b34db --name-status
M       contrib/hooks/multimail/CHANGES
M       contrib/hooks/multimail/CONTRIBUTING.rst
M       contrib/hooks/multimail/README.Git
R095    contrib/hooks/multimail/README  contrib/hooks/multimail/README.rst
M       contrib/hooks/multimail/doc/gitolite.rst
M       contrib/hooks/multimail/git_multimail.py
M       contrib/hooks/multimail/migrate-mailhook-config
M       contrib/hooks/multimail/post-receive.example
```

The status `R` indicates that Git has detected a rename.  Now you get *both* names: the one on the left is from *L* and the one on the right is from *R*.

#### Two-dot notation

Here, I've written `99177b34db^ 99177b34db` instead of `99177b34db^..99177b34db`.  In many Git commands, these are very different.  But for the `diff` command they mean *exactly the same thing*.  There is no reason to *use* the two dots, but also no reason to *avoid* the two dots.  The rules for branch names forbid two adjacent dots: branch names like `feature.one` and `feature.two` are legal but `feature..two` is not.

(Do not confuse the two dot notation with the three dot notation.  This has a special meaning in `git diff` as well.)

#### Commit hashes vs branch names

I've used `99177b34db` instead of a branch name.  You wrote:

```
origin/oldbranch..origin/newerbranch
```

(the single quotes are unnecessary here, so I removed them for simplicity).  In many Git commands, a branch name means the same thing as the commit hash ID to which it resolves:

```
$ git rev-parse master
b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a
```

You can use the raw hash ID, or an abbreviated form of it, to mean this specific commit.  The reason to use a branch *name* is that the commit hash ID identified *by* the name changes over time, as you add new commits to the branch.  The IDs are mostly useless to humans, while the names are created by and for humans.

(A few commands, such as `git checkout`, do something more interesting with the name, so for those commands a name is not interchangeable with a hash ID.)

#### Rename detection is an option

What `git diff` is doing is comparing two *snapshots*.  Each commit represents a complete, full snapshot of *every* source file.  Git takes the left side commit and the right side one and compares the two.  For files that are in both commits, and are the same in both commits, `git diff` says nothing.  For files that are different, or are only in one commit or the other, `git diff` says something.

With `--name-only`, what it says is the name(s) of the file(s) in *R* that differ.  With `--name-status`, it gives the names *and* what made them differ: they can be modified, i.e., present in both commits but with different contents, or newly added, i.e., in commit *R* only, or deleted, i.e., in commit *L* only.

When you enable rename detection, if some file is deleted in *L* and some differently-named file is created in *R*, `git diff` does a bunch of additional computation to decide whether the new file in *R* is actually "the same" as the file in *L*.  This concept of sameness—or *identity* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus)—is actually quite complicated, though Git gives a simple and inscrutable answer: two files are the same if Git's computed *similarity index* meets some threshold.  The default is "50% similar".

The letter-code for a detected rename is `R`; this is followed by the similarity index.  The higher the index, the more-similar the files are.  `100` is reserved for *exactly the same*, which is something of a special case in Git: if two files are exactly the same, they're really only stored *once*, and Git can detect this exact match very quickly.

With rename detection off, you'll just have a file deleted from *L* and a differently-named file added to *R*, even if the two files are bit-for-bit identical.  Since rename detection is a configuration item, two different users running `git diff` on the same two commits may see different results.